# Is it possible "hide" certain branches of a multi-branch pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I don't want to *disable* or filter out other branch jobs.

I want to use multi-branch pipelines, but only present "master" branch to users.

I want to allow only *some* users to see the other branches in the UI.

Is this possible with granular permissions?

The deploy is not connected to source control apart from the jenkinsfiles. "master" branch is the only branch job users need to do their deploys, but admins that work on the Jenkins job should still be able to test jenkins *job* config changes in other branches. And doing something like programmatically checking the user and the branch name and throwing an error is not good enough for me, I don't want users to see the other branches at all.